# java.lang.InstantiationException <com.example.MyViewModel> has no zero argument constructor when use SavedStateViewModelFactory

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm just try to follow this guide to look at MVVM architecture: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide

My problem: When I use two arguments in my ViewModel class "SavedStateHangle" and "UserRepository", then my app crashes with this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7058)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<ru.itschool.jetpackguide.**UserProfileViewModel> has no zero argument constructor**
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)

If I remove UserRepository from constructor parameter (and constructor has just SavedStateHandle), then fragment works (without UserRepository, but it just not crash with this error).

I use my ViewModel with SavedStateViewModelFactory and Hilt + Dagger library like in Android guide to application architecture.

I'm create my ViewModel by this code on UserProfileFragment:

```
private val viewModel : UserProfileViewModel
    by viewModels(
        factoryProducer = {SavedStateViewModelFactory(activity?.application, this, defaultBundle())}
)
```

and my ViewModel code:

```
@HiltViewModel
class UserProfileViewModel @Inject constructor(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    userRepository: UserRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    var userId: String = savedStateHandle["uid"]
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Missing user ID")
    private val _user = MutableLiveData<User>()
    val user : LiveData<User> = _user

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _user.value = userRepository.getUser(userId)
        }
    }
}
```

You can find full code of my project [here](https://github.com/EldarKurbanov/JetpackGuide/tree/stackoverflow).
Maybe someone implemented this guide before me and already knows the answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide a factory to a `ViewModel`, you are giving `viewModels` a way to create an instance of your `ViewModel` if it doesn't already exist. The `SavedStateViewModelFactory` only provides a way to instantiate a `ViewModel` with a `SavedStateHandle` and it obviously doesn't know how to provide your custom repository without some work from you.

So to give it the help it needs, you should probably think about creating a custom implementation of `ViewModelProvider.Factory`, which requires you to implement the `create` method:

```
class VMF: ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {}
}
```

---

For your example, assuming you wanted the fragment arguments available in the `ViewModel`, a simplified implementation would be:

```
class VMF(private val userRepository: UserRepository, private val args: Bundle?): ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {

        if(UserProfileViewModel::class.java.isAssignableFrom(modelClass)) {

            return UserProfileViewModel(userRepository, args)
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

and then you would use your factory in place of the default one:

```
private val viewModel : UserProfileViewModel by viewModels {
    VMF(userRepository, arguments)
}
```

Comment: It's strange that the MVVM guide doesn't say anything about this. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Though this answer does not exactly apply to @Eldar Kurbanov's case? Any of you might have simply forgotten the `@HiltViewModel` annotation above your viewmodel.

Comment: For me that was the case, thanks!